# How to effectively consolidate word and excel VBA functions?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have written code in two mentioned applications. This code in Word places all .emf files into word together with the indicated heading:

```
Sub LoopEMF()
Dim sPic As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim MyText2 As String
MyText2 = "Figure X - Effects of indicated compounds on specified assays."

sPath = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"
sPic = Dir(sPath & "*.emf")

Do While sPic <> ""
    Selection.TypeText (MyText2)
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
      FileName:=sPath & sPic, _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    sPic = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

The second set of code copies a set of cells in Excel (they encode a small table that updates values based on an offset) and pastes that copied information into Word:

```
Sub Insert_Table2()

Dim WdObj As Object, fname As String
fname = "Tester"
Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WdObj.Visible = False
WdObj.Documents.Add
For loop_ctr = 1 To 2
ActiveSheet.Range("I2").Value = loop_ctr
Range("J1:M5").Select
Selection.Copy 'Your Copy Range
WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:= _
wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next loop_ctr
If fname <> "" Then 'make sure fname is not blank
With WdObj
.ChangeFileOpenDirectory ActiveWorkbook.Path 'save Dir
.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=fname & ".docx"
End With
Else:
MsgBox ("File not saved, naming range was botched, guess again.")
End If
With WdObj
.ActiveDocument.Close
.Quit
End With
Set WdObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Both codes are set to loop and do exactly as they're designed. But now I want to combine their respective actions into a single Word file - and I'm really stuck (help?). I cannot see a way to embed the two codes within each other (and not even sure it's feasible). If it is possible to nest the code that would be great - but I cannot conceive how to nest the respective loop functions.

That said, here's what I'd like to be able to do. First, add code to the Word VBA (LoopEMF) so that it increments Figure X by one with each loop (Figure 1, Figure 2, etc.). With that done, it seems it should be possible to modify the Excel VBA (Insert_Table2) so that it opens the Word document with the .emf files, looks for the text string, and pastes the table after a carriage return from the text string. If a kind soul can help me get that far, then it seems the last task would be to set the justification and position of the two inserted objects so that they're on opposite ends of the page and positioned properly relative to each other..

Comment: Well, the "Figure X" is not part of your existing code and it's unclear exactly what you want, although it's possible to guess. But it's an entirely different question than combining the code. According to the Stack Overflow guidelines for asking questions (see the [help]) this makes your question "too broad". I advise you to use the [edit] link to take that part out and put it in a second question with more detail. And before you do, investigate Word's built-in "Caption" feature as that's probably what you want.

Comment: Your second question is about locating a "text string" - but you don't say precisely what this may be - and inserting Excel content after it. You need to be more precise about what you need, here, and this should probably be the main focus of this question.

Comment: Your third question then belongs in another question, and probably should be asked after you get everything else sorted.

Comment: Hi Cindy,My apologies

Comment: Hi Cindy - My apologies for the delayed response. My first question for my second post (no doubt earning more ire from the crowd), why does a forum set the default carriage return to post a response? Anyways, I'm not too good at following rules as you can see. Sorry if my questions seemed too vague - I was doing my best to be clear. But perhaps you didn't take enough time to read my question(s) carefully? If you look again at my code, you can see in (little red letter) on the fifth line down the very section I was referring to. I will unfortunately continue to seek answers elsewhere I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible and doable especially since you've done the work already - read about Excel automation from Word .... Here's a 
[Good start for integrating Excel data into Word](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/integrate-excel-data-word-document/)

Comment: isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: It could be a comment if the answer is expected to be someone writing all the code to do this for him, but I thought it was an effective answer to his question "How to effectively consolidate word and excel VBA functions?"

Comment: Thanks dbmitch - in some ways that was mostly what I wanted to hear. No sense trying to do something if the software simply lacks the coding to do it. How to do it is then much more rewarding when one succeeds. Not hoping to find someone to write code for me - happy to learn the hard way. Thanks for the link - will certainly study.